# How to include a mixin/module in ALL ActiveAdmin controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have written a module - `JsonLog` - that uses the `append_info_to_payload` hook provided by Rails to add some custom metrics to the logging instrumentation. I want to include/mixin this module in **all** the controllers of ActiveAdmin.

I've tried the following, and it works...

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  controller do
    include JsonLog
  end
end
```

...but this will force to me write the boilerplate code in every single model/controller that I'm registered with ActiveAdmin. How do I do this in one place (and in the process also ensure that this boilerplate is never missed out)?

Comment: Do you not have a base controller you can inherit all others from..? If not you can make one without too much trouble

Comment: Does ActiveAdmin have a base controller that I can modify? These aren't controllers that I have hand-written, but auto-magically generated/,managed by ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be shy to read the source.  There is an `ActiveAdmin::BaseController` that inherits from `InheritedResources::Base` that in turn inherits from your `ApplicationController`. If you really need to specifically modify `ActiveAdmin::BaseController` then try this in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin::BaseController.class_eval do
  include JsonLog
end
```